Weapon Mastery and Weapon Cantrips
I'm wondering how the various Weapon Masteries (Cleave, Graze, Nick, etc.) work with the weapon cantrips -- specifically Booming Blade, Green-Flame Blade, and True Strike.

Short answer: Nick does not work with the weapon cantrips unless, as identified in the comments, your class lets you cast a cantrip as part of the attack action (e.g. Eldritch Knight's War Magic, College of Valor Bard's Extra Attack, or Bladesinging's Extra Attack). The other weapon masteries work with the weapon cantrips.
To understand why, let's look at the language:

Cleave, Graze: Cleave says, "If you hit a creature with a melee attack roll using this weapon..." and Graze says, "If your attack roll with this weapon misses..." This should work because Booming Blade and Green-Flame Blade use the language "make a melee attack with [the weapon]" while True Strike says, "make one attack with the weapon". In these cases, the language only refers to an attack or a melee attack, and no language specifically refers to a "magic attack" vs a "weapon attack".
Nick: Nick starts with, "When you make the extra attack of the Light property, you can make it as part of the Attack action instead of as a Bonus Action." The Light property starts with, "When you take the Attack action on your turn..." Because Nick requires an attack action, it's not compatible with the weapon cantrips which require a magic action.
Push, Sap, Slow, Topple, Vex: All of these include the text, "If you hit a creature with this weapon".


Note that Nick will still apply if you're a member of one of the subclasses (e.g. Eldritch Knight, Bladesinger) where the Extra Attack feature allows swapping out an attack for a cantrip, because in that case, you have taken the Attack action. Given that Eldritch Knight is a Fighter subclass (and therefore has access to Weapon Mastery even without multiclassing), this is an important exception to that general rule.

You're read. Good catch -- I've edited the answer to include this information.

@ShadowRanger It's not really clear that you can do that. The Nick attack comes from the Light property, which says: "That extra attack must be made with a different Light weapon". So, you can't use a spell here, only a "different Light weapon".

@Tarod: Assuming you use a Light weapon with the spell, the spell is making an attack with a Light weapon. And either way, you do make a regular attack as well (you only replaced one attack with the cantrip, not all of them), so Light/Nick's properties would definitely apply. To be clear, you couldn't cast the cantrip to replace the Nick attack, if that's what you thought I was arguing, it would be replacing one of your 2+ base attacks, and then you'd make a non-spell Nick attack.

@ShadowRanger I was arguing that, yes. But I don't see that explanation clearly in the answer. Maybe it's just me.

The full sequence of actions for a level 6 bladesinger with two light weapons (one has Nick): Declare an attack action. make a normal attack with a Light weapon. Use the "replace an attack with a cantrip" to cast Booming Blade with the same Light weapon. Now make a two-weapon fighting attack with the second weapon -- during the attack phase if the first weapon had the Nick property, or using a Bonus action if the first weapon did not have the Nick property.
